# Shell script in Automator says "command not found" when passed as variable

Tags: macos, shell, automator

I'm trying to make a automator service that runs selected text in Terminal.
But everything I pass as variable won't run. It always says "command not found".
I tried basic stuff like `open -a Finder`.
When I put the absolute path (`/usr/bin/open -a Finder`), it says "directory not found."

I tried `$1`, `$@`, `"$1;"` and some variations. Also I tried adding my path variable on the top, but that doesn't seem to be the problem, as it's working when I type a command directly.

[image]

When I type the text directly in the shell text field, it runs perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: Show the rest of your script, or what the variable `$f` is supposed to be.

Comment: @l'L'l I updated the question.

Comment: You've got the RSS action set to treat the input as argument. Try setting the pulldown to make it treat the inputs as stdin.

Comment: @TedWrigley now it doesn't fail, but doesn't do anything. When I put the same command directly in the shell script text field, it's working.

Comment: I'm not really a unix superuser, but maybe now you could try command substitution: e.g., replace `$1;` with `$($1);`

Comment: Nope, same as before, nothing happens. For my use case I switched to running a command through Apple Script. But the general question is still open :D